# dropdown menu not showing up sub menu exept first one

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

i am getting problem with drop-down menu i cant figure out the problem. As first sub menu shows up in drop down menu but the rest of the don't shows up for example in main menu contact have further 3 sub menus page 1, page 2 and page3 so only page 1 link shows up and rest of them don't as they get hidden  under page wrapper here is the example http://master2.net.catillo.dk/Velkommen.aspx?AreaID=1

```
    /* Header */

#header-wrapper 
{
}

#header 
{
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 205px;
position: relative;
}

/* Logo */

#logo 
{
overflow: hidden;
height: 160px;
}

#logo h1 a 
{
display: block;
padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #2C7485;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 44pt;
font-weight: 200;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#logo p 
{
padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #388ACA;
font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
font-size: 18pt;
color: #A5D0F2;
}

/* Menu */
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);

#menu-wrapper 
{
background: url(images/img05.jpg) no-repeat center top ;
}

#menu {
padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;
}
#menu ul, #menu li {
list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
#menu ul {
position: relative; z-index: 597; 
}
#menu ul li { 
float: left; min-height: 1px; vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu ul li.hover,
#menu ul li:hover {
position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default;
}
#menu ul ul {
visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 100%;
}
#menu ul ul li {
float: none;
}
#menu ul ul ul {
top: 0; left: auto; right: -99.5%;
 }
#menu ul li:hover > ul { 
visibility: visible;
}
#menu ul ul {
bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
#menu ul ul {
margin-top: 0; 
}
#menu ul ul li {
font-weight: normal;
}
#menu a { 
display: block; line-height: 1em; text-decoration: none; 
}

#menu {  
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px; 
}

  #menu > ul {
 display: inline-block;
 }

  #menu:after, #menu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
}

#menu a {
    color: #CBCBCB;
    padding: 0 20px; 

    line-height: 50px;
}
#menu ul { text-transform: uppercase; }

    #menu ul ul {
      text-transform: none;
      min-width: 190px;
      z-index: 1000;
      line-height: 50px;


}
      #menu ul ul a {
        background: #1b9bff; /* drop down color*/
        color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid  #1b9bff;
        border-top: 0 none;
        padding: 0px 20px; 
}
      #menu ul ul ul { border-top: 0 none; }

      #menu ul ul li { position: relative; min-height:100%; }

#menu > ul > li > a {  line-height: 48px;  }

#menu ul ul li:first-child > a { border-top: 1px solid #0082e7; }
        #menu ul ul li:hover > a { background: #35a6ff; }

        #menu ul ul li:last-child > a {
          border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff; 
}
        #menu ul ul li:last-child:hover > a { border-radius: 0 0 0 3px; }

        #menu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
          content: '+';
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          right: 15px;
          margin-top: -8px;
}

#menu ul li:hover > a, {
      background: #1b9bff;
      color: #FFF;
}
    #menu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
      content: '+';
      margin-left: 5px; 
}
    #menu ul li.last ul 
{
      left: auto;
      right: 0; 
}
      #menu ul li.last ul ul 
{
        left: auto;
        right: 99.5%;
}

/* Banner */

#banner 
{
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
}

#banner a img
{
display: block;
width: 100%;
}

/* Content */

#content {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:0px;
}

.column2 #content {
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}

#content h2 {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30pt;
    color: #2A2A2A;
  float: left;
}

#content .subtitle {
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #00A6FA;
  float: left;
}

#content img {
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}

#content a img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}


/* Sidebar */

#sidebar {
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}
#sidebar1 {
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}
.column2 #sidebar {
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 30px;
}

#sidebar h2
{
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 22pt;
color: #2A2A2A;
}

#sidebar .subtitle
 {
padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 16pt;
font-weight: 300;
color: #00A6FA;
}
/** DIVIDER */

.divider 
{
margin: 30px 30px;
}
/** One Column Content */
#onecolumn 
{
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px 30px 50px 30px;
}
#onecolumn img 
{
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
}
#onecolumn a img
{
}
#onecolumn h2 
{
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 30pt;
color: #2A2A2A;
}

#onecolumn .subtitle {
padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 16pt;
font-weight: 300;
color: #00A6FA;
}


/** Footer Column Content */

#footer-content {
overflow: hidden;
padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#footer-content h2 {
padding: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 24pt;
color: #2A2A2A;
}
#footer-content #box1 section 
{
padding-left: 30px;
}
#footer-content #box3 section 
{
padding-right: 30px;
}
```

here is style.css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300);
@import url('../Settings/form.css');

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #4AA0E4 url(images/img01.jpg) repeat;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #8A8A8A;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

p {
    line-height: 180%;
}

a {
    color: #00A6FA;
}

strong {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2A2A2A;
}

/* Header */

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 340px;
  z-index:1000;
}

/* Menu Wrapper */

#menu-wrapper {
    height: 800px;
    background: url(images/img05.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  z-index:1000;
}

#menu {
    height: 300px;
  z-index:1000;
}

/* Page Wrapper */

#page-wrapper {
  z-index: -1;
    background: url(images/img03.jpg) repeat;
}

#page-bgtop {
  z-index: -1;
}

#page-bgbtm {
  z-index: -1;

    background: url(images/img04.jpg) repeat-x left bottom;
}

#page {
  z-index: -1;
    padding: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/img09.jpg) repeat;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  z-index: -1;
    background: #FFFFFF;

    padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Copyright */

#copyright {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    background: url(images/img10.png) no-repeat center top;
}

#copyright p {
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #1E6BA6;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#copyright a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button-style {
    display: block;
    width: 174px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: url(images/img06.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/** BUTTON STYLE 1 */

.button-style a {
    line-height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #1E6BA6;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/** LIST STYLE 1 */

ul.style1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.style1 li {
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    background: url(images/img08.png) repeat-x left top;
}

ul.style1 a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8A8A8A;
}

ul.style1 p {
    line-height: 200%;
}

ul.style1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

ul.style1 .date {
    float: left;
    width: 78px;
    height: 78px;
    margin: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/img07.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #2C7485;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.style1 .date b {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #2C7485;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.style1 .date a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.style1 .date a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.style1 .first {
    padding-top: 0px;
    background: none;
}

/** DIVIDER */

.divider {
    height: 4px;
    background: url(images/img08.png) repeat-x left top;
}
```

here is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title><!--@Title--></title>
<!--@MetaTags-->
<!--@CopyRightNotice-->

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/css/5grid/core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/css/5grid/core-desktop.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/css/5grid/core-1200px.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/css/5grid/core-noscript.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/css/style-desktop.css" />
</noscript>
<script src="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/css/5grid/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/css/5grid/init.js?use=mobile,desktop,1000px&amp;mobileUI=1&amp;mobileUI.theme=none"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/system/jCarousel/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js"></script>
<!--[if IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--@Stylesheets-->
<!--@Javascripts-->
</head><body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <header id="header">
        <div class="5grid-layout">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u" id="logo"> <!-- Logo -->
                  <a href="/">
                    <img src="<!--@Item.Area.LogoImage-->" Style=" display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:15px; "/>
                    <div class="mobileUI-site-name"><!--@Item.Area.Logotext--></div></a>
                    <p><!--@Item.Area.Logotext--></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div id="menu-wrapper" style="z-index: -1;">
            <div class="5grid-layout">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="12u" id="menu" style="z-index: -1;">
                        <nav class="mobileUI-site-nav">
                            <ul class="dwnavigation" id="navigation" settings="startlevel:1;endlevel:2;template:liclean.xslt;expandmode:all;id:dummy;">
                                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                                <li><a href="twocolumn1.html">Two Column #1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="twocolumn2.html">Two Column #2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="onecolumn.html">One Column</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
<div id="page-wrapper" style="z-index: -1;">
    <div id="page-bgtop">
        <div id="page-bgbtm">
            <div id="page" class="5grid-layout">
                <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <div id="banner" class="dwcontent" title="Top Content"><a href="#"><img src="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/images/pics01.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">

                                  <div id="sidebar1" class="dwcontent" title="left Content">
                                    <section id="sidebar">
                                        <h2>Gravida nibh quis urna</h2>
                                        <p class="subtitle">praesent a lacus</p>
                                        <ul class="style1">
                                            <li class="first">
                                                <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>11</b></a></p>
                                                <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>09</b></a></p>
                                                <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>07</b></a></p>
                                                <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>04</b></a></p>
                                                <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>01</b></a></p>
                                                <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </section>
                                  </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="8u">
                                    <section id="content" class="dwcontent" title="Main Content">
                                        <h2>Integer gravida nibh quis urna</h2>
                                        <p class="subtitle">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna</p>
                                        <p><a href="#"><img src="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/images/pics02.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
                                        <p>Welcome to <strong>Aqueous</strong>, a free responsive HTML5 website template designed by <a href="http://html5templates.com/">HTML5Templates.com</a>.   It features a neat and clean color combination, a spacious content area, and a large banner area, making it a great design for a corporate/portfolio type of website.  And like all of our templates, it is built on HTML5 and CSS3, has full responsive support for desktops, tablets, and mobile devices, and is 100% free to use personally or commercially under the <a href="http://html5templates.com/license/">Creative Commons license</a>. Be sure to check out our <a href="http://html5templates.com/">website</a> for more awesome free HTML5 templates and follow us on <a href="http://twitter.com/HTML5T">Twitter</a> for updates and new releases! Enjoy!</p>
                                        <p class="button-style"><a href="#">Read Full Article</a></p>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                                <div class="4u">
                                    <section id="sidebar" class="dwcontent" title="right content">
                                        <h2>Gravida nibh quis urna</h2>
                                        <p class="subtitle">praesent a lacus at urna</p>
                                        <ul class="style1">
                                            <li class="first">
                                                <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>11</b></a></p>
                                                <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>09</b></a></p>
                                                <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>07</b></a></p>
                                                <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <section>
                            <div class="divider"></div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dwcontent" id="onecolumn" title="bottom content">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <section>
                                <div><a href="#"><img src="/Files/Templates/Designs/html5templates_aqueous/images/pics03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    <h2>Integer gravida nibh quis urna</h2>
                                    <p class="subtitle">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent sed lacus</p>
                                    <p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam pede erat, porta eu, lobortis eget, tempus et, tellus. Etiam neque. Vivamus consequat lorem at nisl. Nullam non wisi a sem semper eleifend. Donec mattis libero eget urna. Duis pretium velit ac mauris. Proin eu wisi suscipit nulla suscipit interdum. Aenean lectus lorem, imperdiet at, ultrices eget, ornare et, wisi. Pellentesque adipiscing purus ac magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque pede. Donec pulvinar ullamcorper metus. In eu odio at lectus pulvinar mollis. Vestibulum sem magna, elementum ut, vestibulum eu, facilisis quis, arcu. Mauris a dolor. Nulla facilisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis  montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed blandit. Phasellus pellentesque, ante nec iaculis, eros justo auctor lectus, a lobortis lorem mauris quis nunc. Praesent pellentesque facilisis elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos.  Donec mattis libero eget urna. Duis pretium velit ac mauris. Proin eu wisi suscipit nulla suscipit interdum. Aenean lectus lorem, imperdiet at, ultrices eget, ornare et, wisi. Donec pulvinar ullamcorper metus. In eu odio at lectus pulvinar mollis. Vestibulum sem magna, elementum ut, vestibulum eu, facilisis quis, arcu. Mauris a dolor. Nulla facilisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis  montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed blandit. </p>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <div class="row" id="footer-content">
                            <div class="4u" id="box1">
                                <section>
                                    <h2>Maecenas luctus lectus</h2>
                                    <ul class="style1">
                                        <li class="first">
                                            <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>11</b></a></p>
                                            <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <p class="date"><a href="#">September<b>09</b></a></p>
                                            <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent a lacus at urna congue rutrum. Maecenas luctus lectus.</a></p>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </section>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u" id="box2">
                                <section>
                                    <h2>Donec dictum metus</h2>
                                    <ul class="style1">
                                        <li class="first"><a href="#">Pellentesque quis elit non lectus gravida blandit.</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Phasellus nec erat sit amet nibh pellentesque congue.</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Cras vitae metus aliquam risus pellentesque pharetra.</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Duis non ante in metus commodo euismod lobortis.</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </section>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u" id="box3">
                                <section>
                                    <h2>Nulla luctus eleifend</h2>
                                    <ul class="style1">
                                        <li class="first"><a href="#">Pellentesque quis elit non lectus gravida blandit.</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Phasellus nec erat sit amet nibh pellentesque congue.</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Cras vitae metus aliquam risus pellentesque pharetra.</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Duis non ante in metus commodo euismod lobortis.</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </section>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="copyright" class="5grid-layout">
    <section>
        <div class="by-catillo"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('http://www.catillo.dk/Default.aspx?ID=170&un=<!--@Item.Area.BrugerE_mail-->&pn=<!--@Global:Page.Name.UrlEncode()-->&url=' + encodeURI(location),'_blank','width=1050,height=750,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');">Support</a>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've posted the CSS twice, but forgot the most important: HTML. And checking your page source, the only option with a submenu defined (ul) is the first one anyway.

Comment: sorry i have added the HTMl now and there are two different css files. the only problem i am facing that sub menu is not showing up on the front its just getting hide behind contents

Comment: Well you've posted a lot of code with out narrowing down what you think the problem is and what you have tried.  However, with a quick look at your CSS and example page, I believe the container holding the NAV element is not large enough to hold the entire drop down and has `overflow: hidden;` preventing the whole list from being fully visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help overflow was creating a problem now its all working how i wanted